# Get queue message count using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I need an example on how to make CRUD operations on service bus queues.

I actually need an instance of Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.SBQueue class, so I can count the messages in that queue.

Comment: Please provide us with some (relevant) code and additional information like what you tried and why that didn't work. SO is not a one-stop-code-shop. In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: [Get message counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-counters)

Comment: _"...so I can count the messages in that queue"_.   Why do you want to do that?  You generally want to avoid doing such things with messaging systems based due to the way messaging apps work in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The older way is to use the [ManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient?view=azure-dotnet)

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient(connectionString);
var queueRuntimeInfo = await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync(queueName);
Console.WriteLine(queueRuntimeInfo.MessageCount);
```

The more modern way is to use [ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet)

```
var client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
var runtimeProperties = await client.GetQueueRuntimePropertiesAsync(queueName);
Console.WriteLine(runtimeProperties .ActiveMessageCount);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is the legacy way. The current way is with ServiceBusManagementClient but I cannot instantiate it

Comment: any idea how to filter by message Session ID?

Answer (score 2):

Use ServiceBusAdministrationClient()

```
var client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(_connectionString);
QueueRuntimeProperties queue = await client.GetQueueRuntimePropertiesAsync(queueName);
int count = (int)queue.ActiveMessageCount;
```