# Get active message count with the new Azure.messaging.servicebus

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there any option to retrieve the Active Message Count of a queue using the new **Azure.messaging.servicebus** package?

With the old **Microsoft.azure.servicebus** you could use **ManagementClient** that exposes **GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync(String, CancellationToken)**

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient("queue connection string"));
var runtimeInfo = await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync("queueName");

var messagesInQueueCount = runtimeInfo.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus"/> OR  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" />     ??     I can't keep up with the newest-new with Microsoft and their ServiceBus library changes.

Comment: The accepted answer here worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706024/get-queue-message-count-using-microsoft-azure-management-servicebus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. The starting point would be a similar management client, [`ServiceBusManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.servicebusmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet). It exposes methods to access entity runtime information such as `GetQueueRuntimePropertiesAsync()`, which returns `QueueRuntimeProperties`. The `QueueRuntimeProperties` object has all the info, including `ActiveMessageCount`.

Answer (score 0):

It is amazing how hard it is to find the solution I was looking for since so much is constantly being deprecated and is a moving target. I finally stumbled on this by importing different libraries step by step and stepped through some in debug mode:

```
from azure.servicebus.management import ServiceBusAdministrationClient

CONNECTION_STR = 'Endpoint=sb://mygroupname.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=sbnamespacerule01;SharedAccessKey=bla bla bla Wm3+ASbGYYqQU='
QUEUE_NAME = 'my-queue'

management_client  = ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
queue_runtime_info = management_client.get_queue_runtime_properties(QUEUE_NAME)

queue_length = queue_runtime_info.total_message_count

print(f"Queue Length: {queue_length}")

# The following attributes are available for queue_runtime_info:

# dead_letter_message_count: 0
# name: 'my-queue'
# scheduled_message_count: 0
# size_in_bytes: 0
# total_message_count: 0
# transfer_dead_letter_message_count: 0
# transfer_message_count: 0
```

I hope it helps somebody, I spent too much on it to even mention. I should mention that one needs "manage" rights on that queue for this solution.