# get Azure Service Bus Queue active message count by SessionId using C#

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to get the count of the messages from an Azure Service Bus Queue, using the SessionId of the messages. 
I found how to count them without filtering by Session IDs here - [Get queue message count using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706024/get-queue-message-count-using-microsoft-azure-management-servicebus), but I really need to count the messages with a specific SessionId.

Comment: You could try using `ServiceBusReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync(maxMessages)` (see [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.peekmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet)), but you would have to provide the number of messages to be peeked (which may not be suitable for your use case?). I'm not aware of another solution than to peek due to the *receive&delete* or *peek lock* behavior of service bus queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of the messages from an Azure Service Bus Queue as said, but by using the particular **SessionId** you cannot get the messages count.

The Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. [ServiceBusSessionReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussessionreceiver?view=azure-dotnet) is responsible for receiving [ServiceBusReceivedMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-dotnet) and settling messages from session-enabled Queues and Subscriptions.

```
public class ServiceBusSessionReceiver : 
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver
```

By using the default [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussessionreceiver?view=azure-dotnet#properties) of this class, we can get the details of **SessionId** and others like PrefetchCount, IsClosed etc..